# How to see exception info while debugging without declaring "ex" variable

Tags: debugging, exception, visual-studio-2017, ide

While debugging, I've always been able to see information about the exception once a catch block was entered even if my catch just looked like this:

```
catch 
{
}
```

Since updating to Visual Studio 2017 though, I am only able to get exception information if I've actually declared a variable like so:

```
catch (Exception ex)
{
}
```

This is super annoying because there are a number of places where the exception is not declared (and normally does not need to be) but I do need to see what the exception is while debugging if there is one. How can I get the behavior back where it always shows me about the exception regardless of whether I've declared a variable for it or not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the locals window you should see a pseudo variable `$exception` that has the exception object for you to inspect. You can also add a watch expression for `$exception` in any of the watch windows.

[image]

Docs with more info and other pseudovariables is at: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/pseudovariables?view=vs-2017

Comment: Cool thanks. I guess there's no way to get the old behavior back then where it automatically showed the little icon/glyph thing where you can click and it expands to show the Exception helper? Not a big deal but it is marginally faster to do it that way.

Comment: I'm not sure but I think what you want is when you break on an exception you see a popup that has the details of the exception? That still happens, but by default exceptions that are handled don't cause the debugger to break. You can break on first chance exceptions (so break whenever an exception happens regardless of it being handled) by changing the behavior in the Exceptions window.

Comment: Hmm... yes to the part about the popup, but no to breaking on 1st chance exceptions. I vaguely remember turning that on once and then realizing how annoying ti was because it breaks on all sorts of stuff you don't want it to. But when manually stepping through the code (or setting a break point in catch block) I've always had the popup. Now I don't get the popup ever... whether I have the variable declared or not. Of course I don't need the popup if the variable is declared but I would still like it.